# React webpack bundle size is large

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, material-ui, node-modules

I have a website that developed using react which has a single page, but the production bundle size is 1.11 MiB. I'm using firestore,firebase storage, material-UI, react-redux for this app app works well everything is fine except the bundle size.

[image]

I used webpack-bundle-analyzer to analyse the bundle size, It seems like nodemodules tooks large size. Here I have added the screenshot.
[image]

**My webpack config file**

```
    const path = require('path');
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/public/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      generateStatsFile : true
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      deleteOriginalAssets: false,
      filename: "[path][base].gz",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      // Compress all assets, including files with `0` bytes size
      // minRatio: Infinity

      // Compress all assets, excluding files with `0` bytes size
      // minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
      minRatio: 0.8,
    })

  ],
  optimization: {
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    minimize: true,
    concatenateModules: true,

  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        // This will apply the loader before the other ones
        enforce: 'pre',
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", {
                "definitions": {
                  "process.env": {
                    "NODE_ENV": "\"production\""
                  }
                }
              }],
              ['babel-plugin-transform-imports',
                {
                  '@material-ui/core': {
                    // Use "transform: '@material-ui/core/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
                    'transform': '@material-ui/core/esm/${member}',
                    'preventFullImport': true
                  },
                  '@material-ui/icons': {
                    // Use "transform: '@material-ui/icons/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
                    'transform': '@material-ui/icons/esm/${member}',
                    'preventFullImport': true
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }

    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

I don't know what I missed here to reduce node-modules size. If we have any other option to reduce bundle size please give me a suggestion for that.

Comment: for lodash , youcan do some optimisation by distructuring importing like `import { isEqual } from 'lodash';`   , then add `sideEffect:false` to your package json

Comment: you probably want to explore splitting your js files into chunks

Comment: its normal to sometimes have a large bundle size. You can use lazy loading so that the client doesn't need to download the complete bundle at once. You can visit https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html for more info.

Comment: @Spring I used mapKeys function from lodash, now i added javascript function for that and I removed lodash code, It reduced 64 kb

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I will try and let you know thanks

Comment: @RishabhSingh I will try this thanks

Comment: also try Preact with `preact-compat`, which should be a 10x size reduction from React, while preserving the same API as React.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MaterialUI, lodash and webpack support [Tree Shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking).
Since you used webpack-bundle-analyser, I am assuming your build process utilises webpack. So your options are the following:

You can use Webpack's [Tree Shaking Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Material UI also has a [Minimizing Bundle Size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) Guide.

In general, a large part of bundle size reduction is dead code elimination.

Once you have done that, you might want to follow React's [Code Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) guide to ensure that the initial load is faster.

Answer (score 5):

You could import lodash funcions separataly

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

instead of

```
import { get } from 'lodash'
```

But I bet this will not reduce drastically your bundle size

Comment: I used mapKeys function from lodash, now i added javascript function for that and I removed lodash code, It reduced 64 kb

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce the build size, you can import functions in this way

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
```

Instead of this

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash';
```

The former will fetch the contents of the entire lodash library and the latter will only fetch one specific chunk of the it. Thus reducing the build sizes by a huge amount.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run webpack in production mode. To do that, you run webpack with the -p flag, like this:

```
webpack -p
```

This little flag does these two things to optimize your bundle size:

1. Enable minification using UglifyJs. It removes unnecessary white
   spaces, new lines, unreachable code, etc.
2. Set the NODE_ENV to “production”. This tells some packages, like
   React, to not include debug code.

if it doesn't work for you please try [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reduce-your-react-bundle-size-webpack-half-amit-gaikwad/)

Comment: Yes, I'm running in production mode

Comment: try to take a look on this article https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reduce-your-react-bundle-size-webpack-half-amit-gaikwad/